# Mutual and Pairwise Independence

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, independence

If a collection $A_i:i\in I$ of events indexed by a nonempty index set I is
mutually independent, then the collection is also pairwise independent. But How can I prove that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You should not call anything obvious unless you already have a proof.

Comment: ok sorry. My bad.

Comment: The requirements for mutual independence include pairwise independence.